# APEX set item value & session state with javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to set the value and the session state with Javascript in oracle apex.  Here my function that I call:

```
function setItemValue(node) {
    $s('P2020_SELECTED', node);

    apex.server.process ('MY_PROCESS', {
         p_arg_name: 'P2020_SELECTED',
         p_arg_value: node
      });
    }
```

The display value (Line 2) will be set but the session state not. I get this error on page load in apex.

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
function setItemValue(node) {
  $s('P2020_SELECTED', node);              
  apex.server.process('MY_PROCESS',{
    pageItems: '#P2020_SELECTED'
  },{dataType: "text"});
}
```

Comment: Particularly if they are using htp.p somewhere in the PL/SQL process, and it doesn't form a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Here another solution for you

```
function setSessionState(pItemName){
    apex.server.process(
        "Dummy Process to Set Session State",
        {  
            pageItems: "#" + pItemName
        },
        {
            async: true, --> change here if you need sync/async
            "dataType": "text",
            "success": function(data){
                void(0);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This is old syntax http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/calling-plsql-from-javascript-in-apex.html

Comment: Further information on this, relating to 18.1 https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMRN/toc.htm#GUID-8BA18416-7E1B-4ADB-BB02-3A2ECE1CA437

Comment: It's good to know it's been deprecated: 6.1.1 apex.server Plug-in and Process Function Async Option Deprecated
In a future release the async option will be ignored and all Ajax requests will be asynchronous. Thx

Answer (score 1):

To further improve the answers above here's my working example (Currently APEX 19.2)

```
apex.server.process(
/* I would suggest creating an Application Process named DUMMY as Ajax Callback with a NULL; content */
"DUMMY",
{pageItems: "#P4_GROUP_ID"}, /* Add comma delimited items eg. #P1,#P2,#P3 */
{
    dataType: "text",
    async: true, /* Async should be true in order to be Asynchronous and then execute your code on success */
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("completed");
        console.log(data);
        apex.region('group-positions').refresh();
        apex.region('group-departments').refresh();
        apex.region('group-instructors').refresh();
        apex.region('group-attends').refresh();
    }
}
```

);